# Proofs for a bi-conditional and conditional premise

Tags: logic, natural-deduction

I have a question about this propositional logic question.

I understand that Hypothetical syllogism confirms that an argument with the form (below) makes sense:

$1.$ P$\to$Q
$2.$ Q$\to$R 
hence, P$\to$R

but how would you make a natural deduction proof for the argument with a bi-conditional and a conditional premise such as: 
$1.$ P$\leftrightarrow$Q 
$2.$ Q$\to$R
hence, P$\to$R

Comment: Do you have [bi-conditional Elim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_elimination)

Comment: I wasnt too sure how exactly I could isolate one part of the biconditional to use biconditional elimination. I am a newbie to this so please pardon my incompetence haha.

Comment: Use bi-conditional Elim so:
$$\frac{P\leftrightarrow Q}{\therefore P\to Q}$$
That you get $1:(\text{the rest is the same as you said})$
\begin{align}
&1.P\to Q\\
&2. Q\to R\\
&\text{Hence}, P\to R 
\end{align}

Comment: Also there is another version of bi-conditional Elim: $$\frac{A\leftrightarrow B~~~A}{B}$$ In this case you want to assume $P$ first, which one are you using

Comment: ah I see, so for the argument: "You’ll only achieve mindfulness if you let go of all desires. But if you do let go of all desires, then you’ll become detached from your loved ones. Therefore, you’ll become detached from your loved ones if you achieve mindfulness" when translated into propositional logic would just use one bi- conditional elimination to come to the conclusion that P --> R using the natural deduction proof?

Comment: the only one I was given was:  1.  A <--> B 2. A 3. hence B

Comment: Yes, just use it once would be enough.

Comment: I think for this one I need to assume that P is the case first. but with all the rules Im not sure how to get from the assumption to the conclusion I am looking for using natural deduction to prove its validity as an argument.

Comment: See the hint in the answer